# How to Export AzMan XML Store to another Machine?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, authorization, azman

Hi
Im trying to find a way to recreate the all of the Roles, tasks operations etc that are currently defined in an AzMan XML store on our Dev box in an XML store on our QA box. Of course just simply copying the XML file to the QA box does not work.

Does anyone know if there is a tool to export or recreate the AzMan XML store on another machine?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually copping XML file from one location to another works fine.  That is how we are doing right now.  However copying file from one location to another location will also copy all users as well.  So if you have test users defined in test XML they all will be copied to another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the XML file will not work IF your group assignments use different domains. Our QA box is in a different domain from our dev and production boxes, so the SIDs do not match, and, as you probably already know, AzMan uses only SIDs for assignments into groups. If everybody and all machines are in the same domain, then the SIDs won't change, and the XML store can be copied from Dev to QA.

Also, check that the permissions for your newly copied XML file on the QA box are appropriate (accessible by the process running your app, and possibly by the users running your app).